# Qt Table Model column overriding

Tags: c++, qt, model-view-controller, model

I have SourceTable (QAbstractTableModel type) of model which should be represented via QSortFilterProxyModel which is part of GUI api.

One of the columns is check box that should represent the state of the row, but it should also be used to trigger state change:

```
unchecked ---check---> checked
```

On check action I have to send a message to server. The server then sends this check info back trough SourceTable (QAbstractTableModel). Then checking should be locked for user intervention.

```
-------------         ---------------    signal    -----------------------   -------
|SourceTable|---//--->|newProxyModel|  <---------- |GUI sort/filter proxy|---|TView|
-------------         ---------------  ----------> -----------------------   -------
    ^                        |
    -----message to server----
```

I should get/set/promote somehow the signal of data change in GUI from newProxyModel.
That is why the "checkbox" column should be "overriden" in newProxy.

Since use of decorator breaks the architecture I am thinking about the inserting another proxy model which should manage this column behaviour. Is this way good to go?

I want to know if it is feasible and what is the the easy/right way to intercept user activity from GUI model (QSortFilterProxyModel) and that from server SourceTable (QAbstractTableModel)

Since I am new to Qt model/view any suggestions and examples are appreciated.
It is possible that I am doing this totally wrong.

Thanx.

Comment: its not clear what your asking here

Comment: @urkon do you want to invoke a specific function when the checkboxes are toggled for each row?

Comment: @Zaiborg Yes. I would like to invoke some function on toggle. But not directly on button but on in model value change. If it is feasible. Normally I would be ussing button clicked but in this case I would have to change others code.

Answer (score 1):

ok, when i get you right, your new toy may be the `QSignalMapper`.

With this thing, you can connect any `QWidget` -> in this case the combobox items you insert to your model <- to a single container that emits a signal where you can determine what object send the signal and custom additional information (like row for example)

on the other side, when you change something in your model (like a value in a table) you need to connect to that signal and can easily get the `QComboBox` of the underlying `QModelIndex` by using `QAbstractItemView::indexWidget ( const QModelIndex & index )`

Comment: This may be missing part of solution with upgrade of the GUI API (TableView). Definitely this is toy I must use in this puzzle.